# Port scanner in UserAgent string - masscan

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, security

I have an account confirmation landing page which requires a token to be sent as a URL get parameter.

Over time, I noticed that the page is getting many requests without a token so I started logging those.

The UserAgent for some of those requests contains this: UserAgent:masscan/1.0 (https://github.com/robertdavidgraham/masscan).

Does it mean that someone is trying to hack my website? 
Should I be worried?

The website is MVC.NET 4.0

Thanks!

Comment: A site that doesn't get under attack has no connection to the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont worry. Probably somebody just trying masscan on the network segment including your hosting provider. You can trace route source IP address and maybe see who that can be. But there are hundreds or maybe thousands of robots scanning internet for running services on public machines every minute of every day, it is perfectly normal.